# phpunit default tests directory (for travis integration)

Tags: configuration, phpunit, travis-ci

I've got a [github project](https://github.com/tkoomzaaskz/SymfonyWorld) which I want to integrate with travis. Currently I execute my tests with:

```
phpunit tests
```

command. I would like to make the tests execute with:

```
phpunit
```

since travis needs it. I guess it's a matter of `phpunit.xml.dist` file, but I can't work out how to set it. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should tell you the answer: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci-php-example/blob/master/.travis.yml

In case that link ever ceases to exist, in your .travis.yml include the following lines:

```
# omitting "script:" will default to phpunit
# use the $DB env variable to determine the phpunit.xml to use
script: phpunit --configuration phpunit_$DB.xml --coverage-text
```

Comment: This small github repository explains everything very well, thank you!